# Shell Script Looping not working while on remote SSH

Tags: linux, loops, unix, ssh, remote-server

I have been trying to make a looping work while accessing via SSH Remote command but it doesn't work. The command works when ran directly in host.

```
scp file root@${SERVER}:/tmp
ssh ${SERVER} "
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done </tmp/file
"
```

I have tried using the single quotes in main script but it causing errors.

```
bash: line n: warning: here-document at line n delimited by end-of-file
```

Any advise will be much appreciated.

UPDATE

**testfile**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Script test**

```
SERVER='client'
ssh ${SERVER} '
echo "inside remote ClientServer"
echo "cat testfile"
cat /tmp/testfile

while read line; do
   echo "${line}"
done <</tmp/testfile
'
echo "Back to MasterServer..."
```

**Terminal Result**

```
root@server]# ./test
S
Kernel 4.14.35-1902.10.7.el7uek.x86_64 on an x86_64

inside remote ClientServer
cat testfile
1
2
3
4
5
6
bash: line 8: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `/tmp/testfile')
Back to MasterServer...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use single quotes to pass the remote commands verbatim:

```sh
scp file root@${SERVER}:/tmp
ssh ${SERVER} '
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done </tmp/file
'
```

---

Ensure you're using `</tmp/file`, not `<</tmp/file`.  The sequence `<<` is used to start a here-document which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: I did try to use the single quotes but I get an error. I have also pushed a script in the remote then call it via SSH but not working too.

Comment: @emyatsuna can you copy/paste the terminal session including both the code and the result?

Comment: @emyatsuna can you also copy/paste the contents of `file`?

Comment: cat testfile
1
2
3
4
5
6

Comment: SCRIPT

SERVER='client'
ssh ${SERVER} '
echo "inside remote ClientServer"
echo "cat testfile"
cat /tmp/testfile

while read line; do
   echo "${line}"
done <</tmp/testfile
'
echo "Back to MasterServer..."

Comment: TERMINAL RESULT

root@server]# ./test
S
Kernel 4.14.35-1902.10.7.el7uek.x86_64 on an x86_64

inside remote ClientServer
cat testfile
1
2
3
4
5
6
bash: line 8: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `/tmp/testfile')
Back to MasterServer...

Comment: @emyatsuna sorry could you paste into the question so that line breaks are preserved?  In comments it's hard to spot where one line ends and another begins...

Comment: @emyatsuna somewhere below your question you should see `share` `edit` `delete` `flag` or similar.  just click on `edit` and you can modify your question.

Comment: cool. It removes the warning but my echo "${line}" inside the loop has no values.

Comment: In my testing the loop runs fine and prints the lines from the file.  Maybe there is still a typo somewhere in your question?

Comment: hi @rtx13, I just had to recopy the script to new one. it solves the problem! thank you! :)